# Set transition for auto filled text

Tags: css, forms, css-transitions, autofill

I have custom styles for forms and added such styles to apply it for auto filled text.

But on my site, I have ability to change theme from dark to light and I need to apply smooth transition for this auto filled text.

Is there any way to do it?

Here is CSS for auto filled text:

```css
.light-theme {
    --text-color: black;
}

.dark-theme {
    --text-color: white;
}

.field:-webkit-autofill,
.field:-webkit-autofill:hover,
.field:-webkit-autofill:focus,
.field:-webkit-autofill:active {
    color: var(--text-color);
    -webkit-text-fill-color: var(--text-color);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    caret-color: var(--text-color);
}
```

I tried to add transition in a regular way, but it didn't work:

```
.field {
    transition: color .5s linear;
}
```

Comment: Did you take note of what https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:autofill#sect1 has to say?